# Wifi limited speed at 24MB

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-speed

I have a problem/mystery I do not know what I do.

I have with  my ISP a 35Mb/s internet speed, the router delivered by the company has Wi-Fi B/G/N at 2.4GHz with a bandwidth of 20. The router is connected to the internet via a VDSL connection.

The question is: my router is set to broadcast using only "N" Wi-Fi and I don't want to change the Wi-Fi settings. Both my notebook and my phone, an Xperia ZL, reach a maximum of 24Mb/s.

The great thing is that my UN46F8000 TV, a Samsung 3D Smart TV, can reach 35Mb/s using the same speed test with the same Wi-Fi settings.

Analyzing the TV specifications in relation to the Xperia, I noticed that both them can work with Wi-Fi A/B/G/N. Already my notebook only Wi-Fi B/G/N. But I do not believe that this is the problem already so that my router broadcasts B/G/N and is configured to only transmit using "N".

The question is why my TV can reach 35Mb/s speed, but the phone or notebook can not?

Note that via the cable speed is 35Mb/s.

Comment: 35MB is a size, MB/s would be a speed of MegaBytes per second - however I am sure you meat to say MegaBits per Second which is mbps.  I say this mostly because is would seem strange if someone complained that there were only getting 24MB/s over wireless! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons why the TV has a higher speed connection:

- There is a better line-of-sight path to the router (fewer obstructions)
- The TV is closer to the router
- The antenna in the TV is longer, of better design or quality
- The Wi-Fi chipset in the TV happens to be of better design/production
- There is a variance in the Wi-Fi implementation on the router that happens to marry up with a variance in the TV
- There is less noise in the path between the TV and router
- The TV has undergone stricter testing for RFI
- The TV is actually plugged in over Ethernet!
- The results of your other tests are not conclusive

I am sure others have something to add.

802.11a only deals with 5GHz channel so don't be worried that your devices do or don't support this - as your router is not 5GHz capable.